# The Model is not loading properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, blender

I'm facing an issue while trying to load a .gltf model using Three.js. The model loads successfully but the problem is the low quality. In fact the model loads pixelated with a very low quality.
This is how it should loads: https://ibb.co/rsk0yTD
This is how it loads: https://ibb.co/fvn4m3X

This is my code:

```
    // get the canvas element
  const canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
  
  // create a WebGL renderer and set its canvas property to the canvas element
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
  
  // set the size of the renderer to match the canvas element
  renderer.setSize(500, 500);
  
  // create a scene and camera
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 500 / 500, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
  camera.position.z = 20;  // set initial zoom level
  
  // CHANGE FROM HERE*************
  renderer.setSize(500, 500);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
  // load the 3D model
  const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    'Bottle.gltf',
    function (gltf) {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
      // called when the model is loaded
      // get the mesh you want to change the texture of
      const mesh = scene.children[3].children[1].children[0];
      // create a new texture
      const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      if (texturename == null || texturename == ""){
        texturename = "copy1.png";
    }
      var texture = textureLoader.load("public/"+texturename);
      // flip the texture horizontally
      texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.repeat.x = -1;

      // create a new material with the texture
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
      // set the new material as the material of the mesh
      mesh.material = material;
    //   add the model to the scene
      console.log(scene.children[3].children[1].children[0]);
    },
    function (xhr) {
      // called while loading is progressing
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    },
    function (error) {
      // called when loading has errors
      console.error('An error happened', error);
    }
  );

  
          // Add a point light to the scene
          const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 1000);
          light.position.set(1, 1, 10);
          scene.add(light);
  
          const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
          scene.add(ambientLight);
          // create a new directional light
            const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            scene.add(directionalLight);          
           const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('texture.png');
          scene.background = spaceTexture;

            // Add OrbitControls to the camera
            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  
  // render the scene
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  animate();
```

I tried to load the model properly but it loads with a low quality

Comment: `mesh.material = material;` why do you change mesh's material, and what for?

Comment: @prisoner849 in order to load the new texture

Comment: Why simply not use `mesh.material.map = texture; mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;` ?

Comment: I was using `mesh.material.map = texture` but the model still loads with low quality